# Dockerfile: pass argument to RUN npm run build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile with these lines:

```
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN npm run ng build --configuration=${ENVIRONMENT}
```

I cant get the "RUN npm run ng build --configuration= to pass the value of $ENVIRONMENT to the npm command.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: Please include your build command and verify whether this is a Linux container.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Dockerfile ARG docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg),

> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the --build-arg = flag.

in order to accept an argument as part of the build, we use `--build-arg`.

[Dockerfile ENV docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

> The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value .

We also need to include an `ENV` statement because the `CMD` will be executed after the build is complete, and the `ARG` will not be available.

```
FROM busybox

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
CMD echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

will cause an environment variable to be set in the image, so that it is available during a `docker run` command.

```
docker build -t test --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=awesome_environment .
docker run -it test
```

This will `echo awesome_environment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your RUN command do this:

```
RUN npm run ng build --configuration=$ENVIRONMENT
```

This should work. Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Thanks.